# Trying to deploy on pythonanywhere and not working

Tags: django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I've downloaded the pythonanywhere installation tool and am trying to deploy with the following line:

```
pa_autoconfigure_django.py <https://github.com/myusername/myproject.git>
```

Then, I get this a key error. My project runs on local.

```
 File "/projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonanywhere/project.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.virtualenv = Virtualenv(self.domain, self.python_version)
  File "/projects/hosproject/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonanywhere/virtualenvs.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.path = Path(os.environ["WORKON_HOME"]) / domain
  File "/projects/hosproject/venv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'WORKON_HOME'
```

Need some help to debug this and try to deploy again. If it helps, I'm new to Django and following this tutorial: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/.

Comment: Seems that you're missing some environment variables required by virtualenvwrapper. What do you get when you run `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` ?

Comment: I think you're running the deploy script on you own machine -- it needs to be run in a bash console on PythonAnywhere.

Answer (score 0):

[As noted by Giles](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/13964/#id_post_55671):

> It looks like you might be running the PythonAnywhere tools from a terminal on your own machine -- **you should run it in a bash console on PythonAnywhere** -- you can start one from the "Consoles" page. (emphasis mine)

However I only got to this `KeyError: WORKON_HOME` after running several commands I shouldn't have (at least it'll make clean up easier):

```
$ pip3 install --user pythonanywhere
$ pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.7 git@github.com:pzrq/djangogirls-tutorial-blog.git
-bash: pa_autoconfigure_django.py: command not found

$ find / -name "pa_autoconfigure_django.py"
$ /Users/pzrq/Library/Python/3.7/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.7 git@github.com:pzrq/djangogirls-tutorial-blog.git
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/pzrq/Library/Python/3.7/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 19, in <module>
    from docopt import docopt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'

$ pip install docopt
...
$ /Users/pzrq/Library/Python/3.7/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.7 git@github.com:pzrq/djangogirls-tutorial-blog.git
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonanywhere'

$ pip install pythonanywhere
...
$ /Users/pzrq/Library/Python/3.7/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.7 git@github.com:pzrq/djangogirls-tutorial-blog.git
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pzrq/Library/Python/3.7/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 52, in <module>
    main(arguments['<git-repo-url>'], arguments['--domain'], arguments['--python'], nuke=arguments.get('--nuke'))
  File "/Users/pzrq/Library/Python/3.7/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 33, in main
    project = DjangoProject(domain, python_version)
  File "/Users/pzrq/Projects/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonanywhere/project.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.virtualenv = Virtualenv(self.domain, self.python_version)
  File "/Users/pzrq/Projects/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonanywhere/virtualenvs.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.path = Path(os.environ["WORKON_HOME"]) / domain
  File "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/../Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'WORKON_HOME'
```

Comment: You could install `pythonanywhere` package on your local machine, and you will find some of the code usable, but to successfully run `pa_autoconfigure_django.py` you need to run it on PythonAnywhere because of environment variables and the fact that a part of the process is `git clone` of the repo.

Comment: Thanks, to clarify the above error only happened when I incorrectly ran the commands on my local machine instead of in a pythonanywhere shell.